Can anyone solve this question using the "assumption" method?

I started with Vin<0 and assumed the 4 possible combinations of D1 and D2. For Vin<0, either D1 and D2 can be on or D1 is off and D2 is on. The book shows D1 off and D2 on as the correct answer, and I am not sure how it chose this to be the correct combination when the other one works just as well.
Note that the bottom diode is D2, and one has to assume constant voltage model (VD-on=0.8V).

We can't assume anything without knowing the values. The operation of the circuit depends on values of R1, R2 and VB.

it doesn't help that both diodes are labelled D1

Edited
We can assume both diodes will be conducting with no external connections and thus have 0.8V = Vf (forward) across each diode and as long as R1 controls this current loop, we know the current is a lot more than a milliamp which for Si diodes is about 0.6V. In fact, due to Vb if positive, D1 (upper) can never turn off regardless of Vb or Vin>2x0.8 amplitudes.
Superposition of equations applies only to linear circuits. In this case, the diodes are nonlinear, if we assume the R values are such that the diodes resistance is either much less when conducting at 0.8V or much more resistance going to open circuit. When D2 stops conducting, the output tracks Vin*R1/(R1+R2)  So although we cannot use superposition, we can apply different conditions for when D2 conducts with Vin < (Vf + Vb)*R1/(R1+R2).
You cannot accurately apply superposition of each branch due to the nonlinear diode VI characteristics. But you can determine the peak currents and thus V ratio of Vb+Vf when the diodes are either ON or OFF and thus the output voltage ratios of Vf-Vb.

If the D1 always ON challenges your intuition, see that Vb, battery always pulls down Vout by some D2 polarity sensitive R ratio more negative than the input, forcing D1 to remain forward biased below this threshold.
While greater than this threshold, Vin keeps D1 forward conducting while D2 turns off.
When in doubt, use Kirchoff Laws for these two "assumption" conditions.
